# Apple Submission - IPA is invalid, it does not include a payload directory

Tags: ios, app-store, release, submission

Hello I have completed an app in sprite kit.  I have a distribute cert and have tried archiving it and it fails out every time at the verify stage.  It says:

> iTunes Store operation failed - Unable to process application at this time due to the following error.  The IPA is invalid, it does not include a payload directory....

Please help I've been stuck for hours.  I have never had this happen when submitting an app.  I read many Google posts about CFBundle Identifier and `LSRequiresIPhoneOS | Boolean | YES`.  None of these have worked at all.

Comment: describe how you create the ipa (do you use xcode?)

Comment: I mean ... it is missing the Payload dir which means the ipa (if it is there) is empty :D

Comment: The Payload dir is named Application, but renaming the folder has not solved the problem.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? What was wrong?